# UIImage loop with image scale - Received memory warning

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, uiimage

I have memory leak problem and i can't find answer since 1 week. :(

I loop more than 20 Images in my photos array I always receive an memory warning.

Maybe someone can help me with my frustrating problem?

**Debug Message**
"Received memory warning."

**Loop in my UIView**

```
images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (Photo *photo in photos) {
    [images addObject:[[UIImage imageWithData:photo.image_compressed] ToSize:videoSize]];
}
```

**ToSize Method**

```
    #import "UIImage+toSize.h"

    @implementation UIImage (toSize)

    - (UIImage *)ToSize:(CGSize)newSize {

        float originalWidth = self.size.width;
        float originalHeight = self.size.height;

        float newWidth = newSize.width;
        float newHeight = newSize.height;

        float xMargin = 0.0f;
        float yMargin = 0.0f;

        float ratioWidth = (originalWidth / originalHeight) * newSize.height;
        float ratioHeight = (originalHeight / originalWidth) * newSize.width;

        // LEFT & RIGHT Margin
        if (ratioHeight > newSize.height)
        {
            // set new image size
            newWidth = ratioWidth;
            newHeight = newSize.height;

            // calculate margin
            xMargin = (newSize.width - ratioWidth) / 2;
        } else if (ratioWidth > newSize.width)
        {
            // set new image size
            newWidth = newSize.width;
            newHeight = ratioHeight;

            // calculate margin
            yMargin = (newSize.height - ratioHeight) / 2;
        }

        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, newSize.width, newSize.height,
                                                 CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(self.CGImage), 0,
                                                 colorSpace,
                                                 CGImageGetBitmapInfo(self.CGImage));

        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(xMargin, yMargin, newWidth, newHeight), self.CGImage);

        CGImageRef cgimg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);

        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg scale:self.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
        CGContextRelease(ctx);
        CGImageRelease(cgimg);

        return img;
    }

@end
```

Comment: What did you find when you ran it through the Leaks instrument?

Comment: why you save images data in an array??? If you save images in Array then defiantly your RAM get full and got you memory warning.

Comment: Hi, do you have an alternative? I saved the images in an array because my next method merge this images into a video file.

Answer (score 0):

"Received memory warning." is not a memory leak, that's the OS telling you it's short on memory, at which point it calls the delegate method associated with low memory:

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
```

To give running Apps a chance to clear out some cruft in order to not have to terminate anything, if not enough space is made apps start getting killed. Unless you can see a leak in instruments I really don't think this is a memory leak.